# Checking kernel update timestamp

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, rhel6

I have to check when was the last time my red-hat based linux server kernel was updated can anyone please help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

uname prints system information.

`uname -v`: print the kernel version

`uname -r`: print the kernel release

`uname -s`: print the kernel name

Comment: date on which my kernel was updated on server ...not the release date ?